# Python: extract all words in between CRs and create JSON

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python but I'm trying to figure out how to parse the data from my NAD amp and generate a JSON from it.

Here's an example what I try to do:

Data: `b'\rMain.AutoSense=On\r\rMain.AutoStandby=Off\r...'`

JSON: `{"Main.AutoSense": "On","Main.AutoStandby": "Off"...}`

And here's some sample data that I've received from the amp: `b'\rMain.AutoSense=On\r\rMain.AutoStandby=Off\r\rMain.Balance=0\r\rMain.Bass=7\r\rMain.Brightness=1\r\rMain.Filters=Full Range\r\rMain.Model=C368\r\rMain.Mute=Off\r\rMain.PreoutSub=Subwoofer\r\rMain.Source=2\r\rMain.Sources=8\r\rMain.SpeakerA=On\r\rMain.SpeakerB=On\r\rMain.ToneDefeat=Off\r\rMain.Treble=6\r\rMain.Version=V1.69\r\rMain.Volume=-20.0\r\rMain.VolumeDisplayMode=Decibel\r'`

Could anyone assist me with this please?

Thank you

---

Update:
OK, managed to get a bit further:

````
rs232_data = rs232_data.decode('UTF-8')
settings_list = findall('\r(.*?)\r', rs232_data)

for d in range(len(setting_list)):
    print(settings_list[d])

Output:
Main.AutoSense=On
Main.AutoStandby=Off
Main.Balance=0
Main.Bass=7
Main.Brightness=1
Main.Filters=Full Range
Main.Model=C368
Main.Mute=Off
Main.PreoutSub=Subwoofer

But I'm still missing the JSON part. Anyone can help me with this part?```
````

Answer (score 1):

#### Logic

- Do some crude index slicing to get the `raw_trimmed` substring
- Split on `\r\r` to get `=`-separated key-value pairs
- Convert to `dict` (may be useful if using data elsewhere in code)
- Return as `json`

#### Code

```py
import json


def str_to_json(raw: str) -> json:
    raw_trimmed: str = raw[3:len(raw) - 2]
    raw_split: [str] = raw_trimmed.split("\r\r")
    intermediate_dict: dict = {}
    for key_value_string in raw_split:
        (k, v) = key_value_string.split("=")
        intermediate_dict[k] = v

    final_json: json = json.dumps(intermediate_dict)

    return final_json


def test_str_to_json():
    raw: str = "b'\rMain.AutoSense=On\r\rMain.AutoStandby=Off\r\rMain.Balance=0\r\rMain.Bass=7\r\rMain.Brightness=1\r\rMain.Filters=Full Range\r\rMain.Model=C368\r\rMain.Mute=Off\r\rMain.PreoutSub=Subwoofer\r\rMain.Source=2\r\rMain.Sources=8\r\rMain.SpeakerA=On\r\rMain.SpeakerB=On\r\rMain.ToneDefeat=Off\r\rMain.Treble=6\r\rMain.Version=V1.69\r\rMain.Volume=-20.0\r\rMain.VolumeDisplayMode=Decibel\r'"
    jsonified: json = str_to_json(raw)

    print(jsonified)

    assert json.loads(jsonified)["Main.AutoSense"] == "On"
```

Comment: It works like a charm - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Json = {} 
for d in range(len(setting_list)):
    print(settings_list[d]) 
    Split_list = settings_list[d].split("=")
    Json[Split_list[0]] = Split_list[1]

print(json.dumps(Json))
```

Comment: Does the job great but for correct JSON format I had to modify it a bit:
```print(json.dumps(Json))```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user17487771 yes true, updated the solution accordingly